# yumvar.update not working in CentOS 7

Tags: yum

I wrote a custom yum plugin in CentOS 5 that worked fine in 6, but is broken in 7.  I've tracked it down to the following code:

```
repos = conduit.getRepos()
for repo in repos.findRepos('*'):
        repo.yumvar.update(conf.yumvar)
```

I added a few prints before and after that code and found that it's not actually doing substitutions, as it does in 6 (and presumably 5, but I don't have a 5 box to check it on anymore).

Anyone else seen this or have any ideas?

Comment: [root@cloud2 ~]# abrt-cli list --since 1445471695
id e03a59c928b74495993800b4caae4c6ca70003f3
reason:         yumconfvars.py:73:prereposetup_hook:AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
time:           Thu 22 Oct 2015 07:37:51 AM EDT
cmdline:        /usr/bin/python /bin/yum list
package:        yum-3.4.3-125.el7.centos
uid:            0 (root)
count:          2
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/Python-2015-10-22-07:37:51-28258